# Executing code while using pip install

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Is it possible to execute some (Python) code whenever I call `pip install my_module`?
Specifically, I have a wheel containing all the modules as well as the __init__.py file and would like to type `pip install my_module` after which the package gets installed and then some other code is executed.

Comment: You can't do that with wheels, that's part of the design. What do you want to do?

Comment: You could create a python script that takes `module_name` as an argument and does some specific task, and then use the `os` module to call `pip install module_name`.

Comment: There is no [post-install hook](https://github.com/pypa/packaging-problems/issues/64) in wheels.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a script, e.g. a bash script. You would execute the script instead of

```
pip install my_module
```

Comment: This should be a comment, since it's fairly incomplete.

Comment: I think the OP was asking if it is possible to automatically execute code after installing a pip package (possibly created by the OP).